# Navbar renders upon devise error even when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have weird problem where in my login page I dont want to render the navbar of the site. The logic I'm using is as follows

```html
<body>
  <style>
    [x-cloak] { display: none !important; }
  </style>
  <div class="<%= 'h-screen' unless params[:controller] == 'listings' && params[:action] == 'show' %> flex flex-col">
    <%= render "shared/navbar" unless current_page?(new_user_session_path) || current_page?(new_user_registration_path) || current_page?(new_user_password_path) || current_page?(edit_user_password_path) %>  
    <%= render "shared/notification" %>  
  <%= yield %>   
  </div>
</body>
```

Now  this works all fine, but whenever I get an error on the login page the navbar suddenly renders which it shouldn't. At first I tought that this is because the line `<%= render "shared/notification" %>` is below the navbar, but that isn't the case. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Presumably, you expect `current_page?(new_user_session_path)` to return `true` in this case? Add a command to render the result to the view (or use the `better_errors` gem, which gives you a console in the page context when you raise an error) and see whether it's actually doing what you think. You may find there's a redirection or something happening that means you're not on the path you think you are.

Comment: Protip is to move anything with this much logic into a helper method so that you can test it in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

So `current_page?` always returns false if it's not a get or head request - see the source code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L549

When you submit the form it's a post request that will render the new view, so it returns false.

You can use other methods to check the path like

```
 params[:controller] == 'users/sessions' && params[:action] == "create"
```